# Apache and limitexcept

Tags: server, apache2, lamp

I am following a CIS document for apache security ([CIS Apache HTTP security](https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/apache/CIS_Apache_HTTP_Server_2.4_Benchmark_v1.1.0.pdf)) and do not understand exactly where to use the `LimitExcept` directive.  Note I am quite new to apache HTTP server.

I have a basic LAMP (ubuntu 14.04, apache 2.4.7) with phpmyadmin and squirrelmail and there are several `Directory` directives, for example in the `apache.conf` and all enabled `.conf` files:

```
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf:           <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/localized-error-pages.conf:#                  <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/error">
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf:#<Directory />
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf:#<DirectoryMatch "/\.svn">
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/javascript-common.conf:<Directory "/usr/share/javascript/">
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf:   <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/icons">
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf:    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/squirrelmail.conf:<Directory /usr/share/squirrelmail>
```

I am confused in which `Directory` directives I need the `LimitExcept`, should it be every single one or just a few or only one?

Not knowing apache that well, how do I choose which are relevant?

Comment: Could you update your question with url to the guide you are following?

Comment: @Letizia, I am not sure if there is a direct link as it must be selected through a form, try this: https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/apache/CIS_Apache_HTTP_Server_2.4_Benchmark_v1.1.0.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [**CIS Apache HTTP security**](https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/apache/CIS_Apache_HTTP_Server_2.4_Benchmark_v1.1.0.pdf) I found that it suggests to add `LimitExcept` directive in all `<Directory>` directives other than the on the OS root directory.

```
 <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS> 
    Require all denied 
 </LimitExcept>
```

This [**LimitExcept**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitexcept) directive restrict unnecessary HTTP request methods, web server only accepts and processes the GET, POST and OPTIONS HTTP request methods.

According to [**Directory**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) manual:

> `<Directory>` and `</Directory>` are used to enclose a group of directives
>   that will apply only to the named directory, sub-directories of that
>   directory, and the files within the respective directories.

So, in your case, I guess you should apply `LimitExcept` to:

```
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf:           <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/localized-error-pages.conf:# <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/error">
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/javascript-common.conf:<Directory "/usr/share/javascript/">
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf:   <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/icons">
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf:    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/squirrelmail.conf:<Directory /usr/share/squirrelmail>
```